# Prove, that $A^+\subseteq A^*$ where $A$ is a formal language

Tags: formal-languages, kleene-star

> Prove, that $A^+\subseteq A^*$, where $A$ is a formal language.

The definition of $A^+$ is $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}}A^i$,  which would be $A^1 \cup A^2 \cup \dots \cup A^i$. Likewise, $A^*$ is $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A^i$ and therefore $A^0 \cup A^1 \cup \dots \cup A^i$.

Suppose, $x\in A^+$. By definition $x\in A^+ \land x\in  A^*$ for all $x\neq A^0$, which is the set of the empty word. We can conclude, that $A^1\cup A^2\cup \dots \cup A^i \subseteq A^0\cup A^1\cup \dots \cup A^i$ and $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}}A^i \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A^i$, that's why $A^+\subseteq A^*$.

Is this "proof" ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have hit the reasoning correctly:
A set $S$ is a subset of another set $A$ *if* $w\in S\implies w\in A$.
Since you are trying to show that $\forall w \in A^+ \implies w \in A^*$, you are proving that $ A^+ \subseteq A^*$.

One more legant way to formally do this is by finding a bijection between the two sets.
Since $|A^*|$ = $|\Bbb N|$ you need to prove that $|A^+|$ is a subset of  $|\Bbb N|$. So you need to find a Bijection (left to you since we dont do Homework for the OP's) from these two sets.
Note that there exists $2^{\aleph_0}$ such functions, so 
 you have a large selection space :)

Comment: Should I add, that I want to show $\forall w \in A^+ \implies w \in A^*$?

Comment: @Doesbaddel, well if you want yes but it is the implicit definition of subset. In general we dont want to add ripetitions in proof.

Comment: Ok, so ... everything is correct? I'm just wondering, because you used the phrase "_almost_ fine" and I don't really know what's still wrong.

Comment: @Doesbaddel i am going to edit my answer a bit, indicating what I would do to prove this.

Answer (score 2):

The "$x\in A^{+}$. By definition $x\in A^{+} \wedge x\in A^{*}$ for all $x\neq A^{0}$" is a bit weird. Not even from a computer science point of view but from a set theory or general mathematical point of view.
First, you're saying the same thing again with "$x\in A^{+}$" which you shouldn't. Then, you're saying $x\in A^{*}$ which is the desired result.

I think a better way to write would be as follows: let $w\in A^{+}$. Then, by definition, there is $i\in \mathbb{N}\setminus{\{0\}}$ such that $w\in A^{i}$. However, $A^{i}\in \bigcup_{j=0}^{\infty} A^{j}=A^{*}$ so $w\in A^{*}$.

Conceptually not different than your answer, just written differently.